# How are random properties chosen for items in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

All items crafted by the blacksmith have a number of random magic properties. However, I've tried to create a helm that provides a bonus to Dexterity and failed after 15 tries.

Are the properties randomly selected from a universal set or are they selected from a set specific to the item being generated?

Comment: I think whether there are subsets for classes is going to be a tough one to answer unless you are a developer or if there is an editing tool like coalesced.bin for ME3, but for D3. However, as StrixVaria has noted, there are likely subsets for different equipment slots.

Comment: @JamesJiao I doubt a tool will help for D3. The point of an all-battle.net game is that a server picks the drops, not the clients.

Comment: True that. Well that's just going to limit our options even more, isn't it?

Comment: Well if we do what Borderlands players did, we can do some frequency analysis where players submit all variations of properties they found on certain items. Seemed to work well there, but that's a lot to hope for until Diablo leaves beta I suppose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more options now.  Starting in [patch 1.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7528695/patch-105-now-available-10-16-2012), Blizzard has been adding recipes that guarantee a particular stat.  First came the Hellfire [Rings](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/#type=ring) (see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89282/how-can-i-craft-the-hellfire-ring) for instructions).

[Patch 1.0.7](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/8608455/patch-107-now-live-2-12-2013#crafting) added five new recipes, each of which comes in four variants.  Each variant comes with a specific primary stat:  [Dexterity](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/#filter=Dexterity), [Intelligence](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/#filter=Intelligence), [Strength](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/#filter=Strength), or [Vitality](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/#filter=Vitality).  For the Jeweler, there are four [Amulet](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/#filter=Amulet) variants.

That's currently twenty-four recipes with a guaranteed roll of some stat.

Comment: This addresses my Dexterity problem directly, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The random properties available are dependent on the specific piece of gear you're generating. Boots are more likely to increase movement speed, for example.

It's a little bit early to have an exhaustive list of what kinds of bonuses are available on which items at this point, but if you're not getting Dexterity on the piece of gear you're trying, you might have more luck on another piece.

Answer (score 1):

You can check all the possible stats an item can have in the auction house. When you select an item, the affixes it can have is displayed in the drop down menu.

Answer (score -1):

While items are generated by the server, the client has a lot of details about affixes, too. And of course it has been extracted ;). The best list I know of is this one. It comes from beta data, but it shouldn't have too many errors: http://d3inferno.com/affixes/ItemAffixes.html

Comment: This is a very hard site for a human to use. You also didn't really answer the question.