# Are stats totally random when crafting?

Tags: diablo-iii

When you craft an item (Shoulders, Gloves, etc...) are the stats affected by the type of item, or they are absolutely random?

For example, the other day I tried to craft some gloves, and I was getting Intelligence and Dexterity all the time, but I thought it was totally random!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63712/how-are-random-properties-chosen-for-items-in-diablo-3

Comment: Uh, how does you getting INT and DEX constantly preclude it being random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each item you craft randomly selects an appropriate number of properties, based on the levels of the item/blacksmith.  As it's totally random, you could very well end up with the same stats on the same items, but it's just luck of the draw (or bad luck, if you're not getting what you want on the item).

For example, last night I created a yellow helm that had 3 properties:

- 1% increased crit chance
- 1.1% [damage converted to health](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Life_Steal)
- an empty socket

I created another helmet right after and got

- 11 Intelligence
- 12 Vitality
- +3 damage on hit (I think, drawing a blank on the last property)

Anyway, the point is, yes, it's entirely random.

Answer (score 2):

Stats on crafted gear are affected by item only in the sense that certain stats/affixes can appear on certain types, at certain levels. For example, only monk gear can get +spirit generation. And low level boots can get +1-2 experience per kill, but a higher level set of boots could get +10.

So to answer the question, yes stats are totally randomly chosen from the pool of affixes available to an item type. There is no bias to make "perfect" items harder to get;it's just statistics that most of what you craft will be mostly useless, like intelligence-dexterity gear, or +health globe/gold pickup radius gear.

The best way to see which affixes an item is eligible for is to look it up on a datamining site. For example, if you are crafting Apprentice Boots from our pal Haedrig, look them up thusly and see their stats list: http://d3db.com/item/i/boots?recipe=205132