# What is the number of different magic properties that a hellfire ring can have?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are random properties chosen for items in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63712/how-are-random-properties-chosen-for-items-in-diablo-3)

I am trying to figure out the odds of getting a specific hellfire ring.  I know that it gets 4 random magic properties.  I was wondering how many magic properties there are that can be on the hellfire ring.  I found this article but was wondering if there is a smaller more concise list.

http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/#entry863922

Thanks!

Comment: That being said, the linked question could use a much better answer.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The linked q/a doesn't provide an exhaustive list for different item types, so I think it's ok to get an exhaustive list of properties for rings here.

Comment: @SadlyNot Yes, but the question itself fully encompasses this question.  That is what closing as dupe is for.

Comment: Let's hope for an update to the other question then.

Comment: 4 upvotes but somehow considered closed.